# Cant include QLineSeries and QChart

Tags: c++, qt

I use the Qt extension for visual studio and when I run

```
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QChart>

void createGraph() {
    
    QLineSeries* series = new QLineSeries();
    series->append(0, 23);
    series->append(1, 22);
    series->append(2, 30);
    series->append(3, 45);
    series->append(4, 56);
    series->append(5, 67);
    series->append(6, 23);
   
    QChart* chart = new QChart();

}
```

I get 16 LNK2019/LNK2001 errors

for example:

> unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl
> QXYSeries::append(double,double)" (_*imp*?append@QXYSeries@@QEAAXNN@Z)
>
> unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl
> QLineSeries::QLineSeries(class QObject *)"
> (_*imp*??0QLineSeries@@QEAA@PEAVQObject@@@Z)
>
> unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const *
> __cdecl QLineSeries::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QLineSeries@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
>
> unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl
> QXYSeries::setPen(class QPen const &)"
> (?setPen@QXYSeries@@UEAAXAEBVQPen@@@Z)
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class
> QColor __cdecl QXYSeries::color(void)const "
> (?color@QXYSeries@@UEBA?AVQColor@@XZ)

Intellisense does not show errors somehow.
This is my `.pro` File

```
QT       += core gui charts

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    login.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    login.h \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    login.ui \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    customDesign.qrc \
    customDesign.qrc
```

Comment: Please also post your `*.pro` file so people can build your example. You probably just missed to add the `widgets` module?

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchart.html) states to use `#include <QChart>`, but that's probably not the cause of this issue.

Comment: It's not the widgets module but the `charts` one as properly described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-index.html#building-with-qmake). So add this module in your solution under 'Qt Modules' as described/show [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-building.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct and runnable code or example based on your code :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QChart>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);
    QLineSeries  *series = new QLineSeries();

    series->append(0, 23);
    series->append(1, 22);
    series->append(2, 30);
    series->append(3, 45);
    series->append(4, 56);
    series->append(5, 67);
    series->append(6, 23);
    QPen  pen(0x059605);
    pen.setWidth(3);
    series->setPen(pen);
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow  window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(400, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**The result is**

[image]

If you can't run this code it means that you have a problem with installation, and you didn't have installed charts.